# Dev C++ program closes immediately when entering letters

Tags: c++, dev-c++

My program closes immediately when I enter a letter. It shows the rest of the code but I do not get to enter the other parts of it. The program closes immediately when entering letters but remains when entering numbers, up until the part where the program is supposed to show the copied information. I have tried putting `getchar();` after every `cin<<a;` but it skips lines and I only get to enter few info. Here is my code:
* I am an extreme newbie, this is by far the longest code I've ever worked on.

```
 #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

string a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,z;

cout<<"Enter Your Name:";
cin>>a;


cout<<"Enter Your Gender:";
cin>>z;

cout<<"Enter Your Age:";
cin>>b;

cout<<"Enter Your Address:";
cin>>c;

cout<<"Enter Your School:";
cin>>d;

cout<<"Enter Your Nickname:";
cin>>e;

cout<<"Enter Highest Educational Attainment:";
cin>>f;

cout<<"What are your skills?:";
cin>>g;

cout<<"How many years experience do you have in this field?:";
cin>>h;

cout<<"What kind of people would you like to have in the workplace?:";
cin>>i;

cout<<"What good values do you have?:";
cin>>j;

cout<<"What bad values do you have?:";
cin>>k;

cout<<"When is your birthday?:";
cin>>l;

cout<<"What is your Father's name?:";
cin>>m;

cout<<"What is your Mother's name?:";
cin>>n;

cout<<"Do you have any children?:";
cin>>o;

cout<<"What is your eye color?:";
cin>>y;

cout<<"What do you dislike?:";
cin>>p;

cout<<"How many are you in the family?:";
cin>>q;

cout<<"What is your favorite food?:";
cin>>r;

cout<<"Your name is:"<<a<<endl;
cout<<"You are a:"<<z<<endl;



cout<<"You are"<<b<<cout<<"years old."<<endl;
cout<<"You live in:"<<c<<endl;
cout<<"You studied in:"<<d<<endl;
cout<<"Your nickname is:"<<e<<endl;
cout<<"Your highest educational attainment is:"<<f<<endl;
cout<<"Your skills are:"<<g<<endl;
cout<<"You have"<<h<<cout<<"years of experience in this field."<<endl;
cout<<"You would like to have"<<i<<cout<<"in the workplace."<<endl;
cout<<"The good thing is, you are:"<<j<<endl;
cout<<"The bad thing is, you are also:"<<k<<endl;
cout<<"Your birthday is in:"<<l<<endl;
cout<<"Your father is:"<<m<<endl;
cout<<"Your mother is:"<<n<<endl;
cout<<"You have"<<o<<cout<<"children."<<endl;
cout<<"You have"<<y<<"eyes."<<endl;
cout<<"You dislike:"<<p<<endl;
cout<<"You are"<<q<<cout<<"in the family"<<endl;
cout<<"Your favorite food is:"<<r<<endl;



return 0;

system ("pause");


}
```

*Edit: Replaced `float` with `string` and added `#include <string>` at the start of the code. The only problem now is the program closing when it is supposed to show the output and when entering a space in the input the next questions are in one line.

Comment: You are reading floating-point numbers, not characters. To read characters, change `float` to `string` and add `#include <string>` in the beginning

Comment: If you want to enter letters, why are you extracting values into `float`s?

Comment: just for future: use more explicit name for variables

Comment: @V. Kravchenko `#include <string>` worked, I am now able to enter letters but it's still closing in the part where it is supposed to copy the input. Also, when adding a space to the input, the next question gets all jumbled up

Comment: `float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,z;` Oh my....

Comment: Dev-C++ is an IDE, not compiler or the output of program you wrote

Comment: The only problem I have now is that when there is a space in the input, the next questions join in one line and when it comes to the part where it needs to copy the input, it just closes.

Comment: @Oblivionchain That's because `system("pause");` is after `return 0;`. Just swap those lines

Answer (score 0):

if x is a float type or an integer type

```
std::cin >> x;
```

reads no letter from std::cin if std::cin starts with a character that cannot be a prefix for a float or an integer type.

So x remains to 0 and your input stream remains unchanged.

For the next

```
std::cin >> y;
```

with y of type float or integer, the same behavior occurs: y remains to 0 and your input stream std::cin still starts with a character that cannot be read by a float or an integer type.

This behavior goes on until the end of your program.

Answer (score 0):

`float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,y,z;`

Variable `a` and other of type `float`. Which means they can store values like `1,10.0,12.3546` e.t.c. As soon as you enter any invalid character for this `data type` this program will exit.

If you want to run your program try declaring all variable as `std::string` and take input via `getline` like this `getline(std::cin,var)`.

P.S : I have assumed here that `var` is of type `string`.

Comment: I have changed `float` into `string` and placed `#include <string>` at the beginning of the code, but it closes right before it shows the output of the program, which it is supposed to show.